# How to extend new instance of module in NodeJS using Backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

So im trying to extend 2 models in NodeJS using Backbone. My files are:

Form.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');

var Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
    _FormFields: [],
    AddField: function(Field) {
        this._FormFields.push(Field);
    }
});

module.exports = Form;
```

Register.js

```
var Form = require('../../../System/Libraries/Form');
var Input = require('../../../System/Libraries/Fields/Input');

var RegisterForm = Form.extend({
    Render: function() {
        this.AddField(new Input('Username'));
        this.AddField(new Input('Password'));
        this.AddField(new Input('PasswordConfirm', 'Password Confirm'));
    }
});

var fn = function() {
    var Module = new RegisterForm();

    return Module;
}

module.exports = fn;
```

And i want every time when i require it and call Render function to create new instance of Form too and extended it.

```
var Module = require('../../Application/Modules/Register/Register')();
if (Module.Render !== undefined && typeof(Module.Render) == 'function') {
        Module.Render();
}
```

When i require it now multiple times im recieving new instance of RegisterForm with (n x 3) fields in Form._FormFields.

Comment: Do you have sample node app which uses Bakcbone collection and model in server side? Would like to take a look how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to get `_FormFields` off the prototype of `Form`. Pass an `initialize()` method to `extend()` when you create `Form` and assign `this._FormFields = []` in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its working, but is there a way to put this code in Form.js so every class, that extends Form.js, to use it without putting it manually?

Comment: Where did you put it? It should be in `Form.js`, in the call to `extend()`. Then if you extend `Form` and you define an `initialize()` method on the subclass, call `Form`'s `initialize()` from it.

Comment: I putted it in Register.js, now when i putted it in Form.js like you said, its working like i wanted. Thank you :)